# newsAPI import error cannot import name 'NewsApiClient' from 'newsapi'

Tags: python, python-3.x, newsapi

i wanted to make a program for news using the NewsApi.org Api, but i've got a problem i dont know how to solve.
my code is:

```
import requests
from newsapi import NewsApiClient

url = ('https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?'
       'q=Apple&'
       'from=2023-06-11&'
       'sortBy=popularity&'
       'apiKey=0e24ed7870d04cc392d0a5804381faf7')

response = requests.get(url)
r = 0
print (r.json)
```

and the error im getting is:
ImportError: cannot import name 'NewsApiClient' from 'newsapi' (c:\Users\tomh2\Desktop\newsapi.py)

(whole error)

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\tomh2\Desktop\news.py", line 2, in 
from newsapi import NewsApiClient
ImportError: cannot import name 'NewsApiClient' from 'newsapi' (c:\Users\tomh2\Desktop\newsapi.py)

i hoped to get the latest apple news, but just got this error!

Comment: what package did you install ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main script (c:\Users\tomh2\Desktop\news.py) cannot import `NewsApiClient`. It seems that you do not even need this class, as it is not used in your main script. Change the code of your `news.py` as follows:

```py
import requests

url = ('https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?'
       'q=Apple&'
       'from=2023-06-11&'
       'sortBy=popularity&'
       'apiKey=0e24ed7870d04cc392d0a5804381faf7')

response = requests.get(url)

result = response.json()

print(result)
```

This should return the expected response.